# Kotlin supervisorScope fails even though wrapped in try catch

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Considering such code:

```kotlin
coroutineScope {
  try {
    supervisorScope { launch { error("") } }
  } catch (t: Throwable) {
    println("logs and stuff")
  }
}
```

running this code, I'd expect to see `logs and stuff` in the output, but it propagates exception all the way up to the origin scope, which will fail unless it has `CoroutineExceptionHandler` installed.

Question is: is this by design, or a bug (if so — will open an issue)?

P.S. Switching to inner `coroutineScope` "fixes" the issue

```kotlin
coroutineScope {
  try {
    coroutineScope { launch { error("") } }
  } catch (t: Throwable) {
    println("now you'll see it")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working as designed.

The error in your first example does not actually propagate to the outer scope. Instead the error is captured by the supervisor scope, and the outer scope continues running normally *without* encountering an error. This is the expected behaviour of a supervisor scope, and it's why the `catch` block never runs.

You can demonstrate this by adding some more code after the catch block. Code inside the outer scope but after the catch block will continue to run as normal, indicating that no error was encountered in the outer scope.

```kotlin
suspend fun main(): Unit = coroutineScope {
    try {
        supervisorScope { launch { error("") } }
    } catch (t: Throwable) {
        println("you won't see this")
    }
    println("but you will see this")
}
```

Since the error doesn't propagate outside the supervisor scope, it is instead passed to the scope's uncaught exception handler. That's why you see the error being printed to the standard error stream. It does not indicate that the application crashed.

Comment: Well, TIL. Thanks a lot for this clear explanation.